# Oracle security equivalent in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, security, oracle11gr2

As you knows Oracle has to many products for security like an Database Vault,Oracle Label Security,Audit Vault and Database Firewall, Transparent Data Encryption etc.. 
Microsoft SQL Server has a product like above? It can be directly Microsoft product or 3rd party products.

Comment: Transparent Data Encryption is covered in SQL Server see [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: For the other things you might want to search in the manual's [security section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/security-center-for-sql-server-database-engine-and-azure-sql-database?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Oracle Label Security - seems to be similar to [RLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-2017), SQLServer has [Audit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017) too.

Comment: Thanks all i am reading but all is not sufficient like Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This topic is extremely extensive. Go to [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) for more specific questions.

- **Database Vault:** [Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017), [Server Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/server-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017) & [Database Roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017), TDE, and Policy-Based Management.
- **Oracle Label Security**: [Row-Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-2017)
- **Audit Vault**: [Server/Database audits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)
- **Database Firewall**: [Azure Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-security-tutorial), for on-premises you'd go with
  Windows Firewall
- **Transparent Data Encryption**: [TDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption?view=sql-server-2017)